# Marking Stores that can be robbed Offline

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is there an option to mark stores that can be robbed on the offline map? I have played online and they are all listed on the map, but as soon as I go back to story mode/offline, the stores are no longer marked on my map.

Comment: Do you need them marked within the game, or can you use the interactive map by IGN: http://uk.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county

Comment: Yo could also look at this mod https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/rob-able-store-markers

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I need them to be marked on the map. My computer screen doesn't handle well between the changes in resolution between my desktop and the game

Comment: Are you restricted to once computer? If so you could print the map out and stick it on the wall?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an in-game option to mark mini-marts and liquor stores on the map in GTA V story mode. This is a feature that is only available in GTA Online.

As posted in the comments, there is a [mod](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/rob-able-store-markers) for GTA V PC that places map markers on these locations. Alternatively, you can use third-party resources such as [IGN's interactive map](https://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county) to find these locations.